# Customize Django User Table View with extended fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

So I'd like to show different columns on the auth/users page

I have extended my user model by placing this in my models.py

```
class InsiderUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100L, blank=True)
```

I am able to edit the field in admin by placing the following in admin.py:

```
class InsiderUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = InsiderUser
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'insideruser'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (InsiderUserInline, )
```

However changing the list_display I am having some trouble I have tried:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (InsiderUserInline, )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', InsiderUser)
```

This just tells me that there is an InsiderUser object, which makes me feel like I'm on the right path because the following all produced errors:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (InsiderUserInline, )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', InsiderUser.company_name)

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (InsiderUserInline, )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', InsiderUser[company_name])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the company name is stored in a separate table, you can display it using a custom admin method as given below.

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (InsiderUserInline, )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'display_company_name', )

    def display_company_name(self, request):
        if InsiderUser.objects.filter(user__id = request.id):
            return InsiderUser.objects.get(user__id = request.id).company_name
        else:
            return None
    display_company_name.short_description = 'Company Name'

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```